# Excel VBA IE HTML Webpage dropdown list in <DIV> <SVG> element

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working to auto-fill a form on a website and not able to get through this one field which is a dropdown list inside a  element.

The HTML code appears as below, when I manually select the value on webpage, there is one more  added (shown after HTML code).

```html
<div class="county-select-input">
    <div class=" css-2b097c-container" id="OES_area">
    <div class=" css-yk16xz-control">
    <div class="css-1hwfws3">
    <div class=" css-1wa3eu0-placeholder">Type search term here</div>
    <div class="css-1g6gooi">
    <div style="display: inline-block;"><style>input#react-select-3-input::-ms-clear {display: none;}</style><input tabindex="0" id="react-select-3-input" style="background: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none; width: 19px; color: inherit; font-size: inherit; box-sizing: content-box; opacity: 1;" spellcheck="false" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" value="" autoComplete="off" autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect="off">
    <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; overflow: scroll; font-family: Source Sans Pro,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; white-space: pre; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="css-1wy0on6"><span class=" css-1okebmr-indicatorSeparator"></span>
    <div class=" css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="css-19bqh2r" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 20 20" focusable="false" width="20" height="20"><path d="M 4.516 7.548 c 0.436 -0.446 1.043 -0.481 1.576 0 l 3.908 3.747 l 3.908 -3.747 c 0.533 -0.481 1.141 -0.446 1.574 0 c 0.436 0.445 0.408 1.197 0 1.615 c -0.406 0.418 -4.695 4.502 -4.695 4.502 c -0.217 0.223 -0.502 0.335 -0.787 0.335 s -0.57 -0.112 -0.789 -0.335 c 0 0 -4.287 -4.084 -4.695 -4.502 s -0.436 -1.17 0 -1.615 Z" /></svg></div></div></div><input name="OES_area" type="hidden" value=""></div></div>
```

*This div Webpage adds this new  when I select the value manually.*
`<div class="css-1uccc91-singleValue">Baldwin County - Daphne-Fairhope-Foley, AL</div>`

[This is how field looks like webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N2T7.png)

I have tried multiple ways to address this, no result.. posting two ways i tried.
**Option 1:**

```
Dim inputfield_County As Object
Set inputfield_County = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("css-1g6gooi")(0).getElementsByTagName("div")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
MsgBox inputfield_County
If inputfield.Length > 0 Then
    inputfield_County(0).Focus
    inputfield_County(0).Click
    inputfield_County(0).Value = "Butler County - Southeast Alabama nonmetropolitan area"
    Call iewait(ie)
End If
```

**Option 2:**

```
 Dim HTMLdoc_County_00 As htmlDocument
    Dim selectElement_County_00 As HTMLSelectElement
    Dim evtChange_County_00 As Object
    Set HTMLdoc_County_00 = ie.Document
    Set evtChange_County_00 = HTMLdoc_County_00.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    evtChange_County_00.initEvent "change", True, False
    Set selectElement_County_00 = HTMLdoc_County_00.getElementsByClassName("css-19bqh2r")(0)
    selectElement_County_00.innerText = "Fayette County - Northwest Alabama nonmetropolitan area" 'London1
    'Set selectElement_County_00 = HTMLdoc_County_00.getElementsByClassName("css-1g6gooi")(0).getElementsByTagName("div")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
    selectElement_County_00.Value = "Fayette County - Northwest Alabama nonmetropolitan area" 'London1
    'Set selectElement_County_00 = HTMLdoc_County_00.getElementsByClassName(" css-1wa3eu0-placeholder")(0)
    ' css-1wa3eu0-placeholder/ css-yk16xz-control/
    MsgBox selectElement_County_00
    'selectElement_County_00.Focus
    'selectElement_County_00.Click
'    selectElement_County_00.Value = "Fayette County - Northwest Alabama nonmetropolitan area" 'London1
'    'MsgBox selectElement_County_00.innerText
'    selectElement_County_00.dispatchEvent evtChange
    Call iewait(ie)
```

Any help or guidance is highly appreciated...

Comment: Is the url publically accessible?

Comment: @QHarr - Yes, you could access it, however, you will need to create your log in credentials to do so. However, website is for very specific purpose. Please let me know if you need the link.